# Toggle box closed if other opens

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me out with the following code? Can't get it right.

I want it to close opens toggle when clicking on new/other one.

I have this at the moment:

http://jsfiddle.net/78tDj/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    // Find the toggles and hide their content
    $('.toggle').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.toggle-content').hide();
    });

    // When a toggle is clicked (activated) show their content
    $('.toggle a.toggle-trigger').click(function(){
        var el = $(this), parent = el.closest('.toggle');

        if( el.hasClass('active') )
        {
            parent.find('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
            el.removeClass('active');
        }
        else
        {
            parent.find('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
            el.addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });

});  //End
```

Comment: Thnx guys it worked !

Comment: how to close now an open toggle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide them in your `click` handler:

```
$('.toggle a.toggle-trigger').click(function(){
    var el = $(this), parent = el.closest('.toggle');

    $('.toggle .toggle-content').slideUp(); // <- added this!!!!
    //...
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78tDj/4/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to call each, it's redundant. Also, simply hide all toggles before opening a new one ..done :-)

```
$('.toggle a.toggle-trigger').click(function() {                
    var el     = $(this),
        parent = el.closest('.toggle');

    $('.toggle .toggle-content').slideUp();

    if (!el.hasClass('active')) {
        $('.toggle a.toggle-trigger').removeClass('active');

        el.addClass('active');
        parent.find('.toggle-content').slideDown();
    }
    else {
        el.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78tDj/10/

Comment: thnx, but now i cant close an open toggle

Comment: Updated fiddle to work on all toggles, also fixed 'active' class. Check as answer if it's what you need, tnx. This is probably not the most optimized code now, but i'm sleepy...

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want to achieve?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    // Find the toggles and hide their content
    $('.toggle-content').hide();

    // When a toggle is clicked (activated) show their content
    $('.toggle a.toggle-trigger').click(function(){
        var el = $(this), parent = el.closest('.toggle');


        $('.toggle-content').hide();

        if( el.hasClass('active') )
        {
            parent.find('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
            el.removeClass('active');
        }
        else
        {
            parent.find('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
            el.addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });

});  //End
```